# How to pass arg in ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I'm using jenkins and have prepared `x.sh`, it's :

```
ssh -tt $2 ' \
echo 1111111;\
echo $1;\
'
```

and then I run this x.sh in jenkins's jump machine
`./x.sh hello tom@10.10.10.10`

Then result is

```
1111111
```

Ok, How to print

```
1111111
hello
```

Comment: Can each `'` be replaced with a `"`?

Comment: @Milag 3q，it works in simple commands but will make my long commands fail and can't figure why……

Comment: Next guess is placing everything on 1 line and drop both `\\`